# Do messages sent to and by Slackbot in a DM count towards a free team's message limit?

Tags: slack

If users use slackbot heavily, but only in DMs, will this use up the 10,000 message limit for a free team?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as far as I know every message counts in every channel, including message from Slackbot and including messages in DMs. If you need an official answer you may want to sent a mail to the Slack team though.

One way to mitigate the problem is to have a bot that constantly deletes older messages from channels which are no longer relevant.